# Different behavior pop-up window css

Tags: css, popup

Code below works good on local computer, but on remote server pop-up window doesn't consider scroll width and appears on the top of the page even when i scrolled the page up to the bottom. Problem appears only in IE and only on remote server. Files are the same. What should I check?

HTML

```
<div style="position:absolute;">
    <div id="a_div">
        123
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#a_div {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    width:850px;
    top:35px;
    border:1px solid #B1B8C7;
    background:white;
    z-index:3000;
}
```

JS

```
function showaDiv() {
    var div = document.getElementById('a_div');
    var width = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (div) {
        div.style.left = Math.round((width-850)/2)+'px';
        div.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('a_bgdiv').style.display = 'block';
    }    
}
```

Comment: According to your css it should be appeared at top 35px.

Comment: Why does it work good (as i need) in firefox and chrome?

Comment: Check my answer and the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/2y9ZC/) if you want to center it vertically

```
function showaDiv() {
    var div = document.getElementById('a_div');
    var width = document.body.clientWidth;
    var height = getDocHeight();
    if (div) {
        div.style.left = Math.round((width-850)/2)+'px';
        div.style.display = 'block';
        div.style.top = Math.round((height-div.clientHeight)/2)+'px';
        //document.getElementById('a_bgdiv').style.display = 'block';
    }    
}

function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
```

Just added the top.